# Unable to fetch applications info from an Archived Team or a Channel in archived Team

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams, microsoft-graph-teams

Unable to fetch applications info from an Archived Team or a Channel in archived Team. I get “Forbidden” return code. I can query the properties of the Team but not the app's info.

Please see the queries to get applications from an archived team and from a channel in Archived team and the response we got  below:

```
GET /teams/b335b674-b133-4e82-a17f-6ab70374fdb9/channels/19:QibtKiRAKAigjycZ-gUpcplNzm9Tfk_cXwDXIl4VnBk1@thread.tacv2/tabs

{
    "error": {
        "code": "Forbidden",
        "message": "Forbidden",
        "innerError": {
            "date": "2021-10-28T17:03:07",
            "request-id": "4373f190-1cf7-42c0-96f6-99e8f5953726",
            "client-request-id": "7900d048-ec91-6c46-74bc-4d7c0f269262"
        }
    }
}
```

```
GET /teams/b335b674-b133-4e82-a17f-6ab70374fdb9/installedApps

{
    "error": {
               "code": "Forbidden",
               "message": "Forbidden",
               "innerError":{ 
                   "date": "2021-10-07T11:49:41", 
                   "request-id": "416cee25-bbc8-4dab-8b20-08052275dff7", 
                   "client-request-id": "bab777fa-8337-82df-5118-379faa2ab891" 
               }
   }
}
```

Please let me know whether this is the desired behavior or a potential issue. Also, let me know if there is any workaround.

Comment: Have you provided the [permissions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/channel-list-tabs?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#permissions)? Is it working for active teams?

Comment: Yes. It works perfectly fine for active Teams. All the necessary permissions are present.

Comment: What flow did you use to get to token? Are you an owner of the team you're trying to access? Beta or v1.0? `When a team is archived, users can no longer send or like messages on any channel in the team` might have something to do with it.

Comment: Could you please confirm on the above reply by Stephan?

Comment: Sorry for replying late on this. The issue was acknowledged and fixed by Microsoft. Was waiting for their confirmation before replying.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry for replying late on this. The issue was acknowledged and fixed by Microsoft. Was waiting for their confirmation before replying.